# jquery link with @data-rel and link with @data-transition pointing the same page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the below code or you can check at jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/HzGDm/)
I am not sure what I did wrong. if you click on the link #1, then click on #2, and #3, then the link #2 and #3 all become dialog box.

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header"><h1>Page 1</h1></div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <h2>
            <a href="#page2" data-rel="dialog" >1. Click this link first: Display Dialog</a></h2>

        <h2>Then let's try some transitions!</h2>
        <p>2. <a href="#page2" data-transition="fade">Fade to second page</a></p>
        <p>3. <a href="#page2" data-transition="flip">Flip to second page</a></p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer"><h1>footer</h1></div>
</div>


<div id="page2" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header"><h1>page 2</h1></div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>This is page 2</p>
        <p><a href="#page1">Go back to first page</a></p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">Page Transitions</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This issue is jquery mobile is initing the page to be a dialog and applies the style.  If you do the page link first the dialog link does the pop but still looks like a page.  How to prevent this, not sure yet.

Comment: Not even going to comment on my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution is through multi page document,split the single page.html into two pages and reload the page for each navigation.By reloading the page, page is enhanced again with the new attributes.

```
<!------ page1.html -------->

<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>    
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css">        
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>        
    <script>

var pageChange =  function(event){
    var target = event.target;
    var transition = $(target).jqmData( "transition" ) || $.mobile.defaultPageTransition;
    var role = $(target).jqmData( "rel" );
    $.mobile.changePage('page2.html', {reloadPage:true, transition:transition, role:role});
}

$(document).delegate('#page1 #fadeAnchor', 'click', pageChange);
$(document).delegate('#page1 #flipAnchor', 'click', pageChange);
$(document).delegate('#page1 #dialogAnchor', 'click', pageChange);

    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header"><h1>Page 1</h1></div>
    <div data-role="content">
             <h2><a id="dialogAnchor" href="javascript:void(0);" data-rel="dialog" >Click this link first: Display Dialog</a></h2>

        <div style="margin-top:2em"></div>

            <h2>Then let's try some transitions!</h2>
            <p><a id="fadeAnchor" href="javascript:void(0);" data-transition="fade">Fade to second page</a></p>
            <p><a id="flipAnchor" href="javascript:void(0);" data-transition="flip">Flip to second page</a></p>


    </div>
    <div data-role="footer"><h1>footer</h1></div>
</div>
</body></html>



<!--------------------page2.html ------------------>

<div id="page2" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header"><h1>page 2</h1></div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>This is page 2</p>
        <p><a href="page1.html">Go back to first page</a></p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">Page Transitions</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When jQuery Mobile initializes a pseudo-page, it adds classes specific to how the pseudo page will be displayed (pseudo-pages being `data-role="page"` and `data-role="dialog"` elements). So if you initialize as a dialog then it will get dialog classes, and the same for regular pages.

You can however combat this by manually changing the pseudo-page's classes. For example:

```
//wait for first page to initialize to bind to its links
$(document).delegate('#page1', 'pageinit', function () {

    //find links in the first page and bind a click event handler to them
    $(this).find('a').bind('click', function () {

        //this link is opening a regular page
        if ($(this).attr('data-rel') !== 'dialog') {

            //update the necessary attributes/classes to show a regular page
            $('#page2').attr('data-role', 'page').removeClass('ui-dialog')
                       .find('.ui-header').removeClass('ui-corner-top')
                       .end().find('.ui-footer').removeClass('ui-corner-bottom')
                       .end().find('.ui-dialog-contain').children().unwrap();
        } else {

            //this link is opening a dialog
            $('#page2').attr('data-role', 'dialog').addClass('ui-dialog')
                       .find('.ui-header').addClass('ui-corner-top')
                       .end().find('.ui-footer').addClass('ui-corner-bottom')
                       .end().children().wrapAll('<div role="dialog" class="ui-dialog-contain ui-corner-all ui-overlay-shadow" />');
        }
    });
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/HzGDm/9/

This isn't a complete solution. You will notice that if you open the second page as a regular page and then open it as a dialog, it will appear much like a dialog but it won't have the "X" icon to close the dialog. That in and of itself isn't much of an obstacle, but you may run into other issues like that.